# Counting Kernels of Corn

Tags: vb.net, image, algorithm, image-manipulation

I'm looking for some guidance here. I primarily am a frontend developer. What I am trying to figure out is how an algorithm can be implemented to count kernels on an ear of corn.

From my initial research it seems there are a couple of different directions to go. Main ones I have seen are a SIRF type of implementation and others call for conversion to the HSV color space or LAB color space in order to then to normalizations and then counting.

For reference usually the corn that will be counted is "dent" corn. Here is an example:
[image: Dent Stage Corn Ear]

This will be implemented in VB.net, but I can always translate the algorithm if needed.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: which corn kernel version?

Comment: @Jake Holland I would strongly suggest you put this in Code Golf & Puzzles.

Comment: A quite widely used (the most widely used?) Computer Vision system is [OpenCV](http://opencv.org), but I do not think it supports VB.net -- any chance you could use a more suitable platform?

Comment: @J.V.A.  Wish I could... :)

Comment: Then I'm guessing you are going to be doing much of the heavy lifting yourself.  What you probably want is "edge detection".  Here's a starting point: http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/alumni/bGreen/www.pages.drexel.edu/_weg22/can_tut.html

Comment: It's **not easy**, how I know: ***we do it where I work***. I would offer some guidance, but can't post what we do as I would like to keep my job :) Sorry I can't be more of guidance.

Comment: I can tell you it involve's the intensity, get average count of ears for an acre, count the kernels for 3 ears in that acre (random). There's more, but that is a little more information than you have I would assume... Some do it by weight which will yield many results because of moisture and such, not recommended.

Comment: One thing I'd want to know is whether you're processing just that image above, or building a tool to process images in general.

Comment: @clweeks I'm looking to create a tool that given an image of corn it will count the kernels on the ear

Comment: @Codexer We have a process in place already where you can calculate the estimation, but you must count the ear's row length and width. We would like to automate that process of manually counting the kernels.

Comment: That'll be some pretty neat code. I've played with collecting pools of like-hued colors in a list of objects and always blow the heap -- so I'm clearly doing it wrong. I also tried to write code that identified sunflowers in an image and there was so much variation that I never got it working. So this is of interest to me, but I'm of no help to you. :-)

Comment: If you wanted to use openCV, you could try the wrapper Emgu CV.